# Parsing full content of Word document with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to write a generic method to extract everything from a word document to text file by looping through paragraph and shapes.

I am able to parse 90% of the document using the code below. However this code is not reading contents from few tables.

```
Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWordApp.Visible = False
Set objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(strWordDocPath)

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = objFso.createTextFile(strTextFilePath)
Set colParagraphs = objWordDoc.Paragraphs


For Each objParagraph In colParagraphs
    lineText =Trim(objParagraph.Range.Text)
    If lineText <> "" Then
       oFile.Write lineText & vbCrLf
    end if
next
```

I am unable to extract few texts in a table from MS word document. The issue is only with a few texts and tables and I am able to read most contents from the document using my code.

Word document is present in the below link -

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1C7jj9dLG2aTXJNRGt6QTBVUUE/view?usp=sharing

The main issue is with parsing first table in the document. This document is generated by an application and I do not have any control on the formatting of the contents.

Can some one help me to read the complete contents from the attached document?

Comment: ? activedocument.Tables.Count  
 0  
? activedocument.Shapes.Count  
 3  
? activedocument.Shapes(1).Name  
Text Box 153  
? activedocument.Shapes(2).Name  
Group 151  
? activedocument.Shapes(3).Name  
Group 149

Comment: **? activedocument.Shapes(1).AlternativeText**
> Text Box: ISDN gives you integrated digital access to voice and data

Comment: **? Activedocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text** >
ISDN gives you integrated digital
access to voice and data networks. It is made up of a digital transmission circuit between the NT1 at your premises and the local ISDN exchange .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lead for you:

```
Sub test()
    Dim tCel As Cell, cellText As String

    For Each tCel In ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Tables(1).Range.Cells
        cellText = Trim(tCel.Range.Text)
        Debug.Print cellText
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks WinterKnell.I am able to read the cell values now.But the challenge is to write a generic method to extract everything from a word document to text file by looping through paragraph and shapes.I am not sure how to do it.Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: There is no 100% generic method. Any reasonably comprehensive solution will be a mashup of techniques like this and you'll never be absolutely certain you've sucked a doc dry, even if you can account for every word visible on screen. Text will be hidden in metafiles, as alternative paragraphs in forms, as comments, review corrections, even in vba. :(